# How to convert this code-based WPF tooltip to Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, tooltip

The following ToolTip code works in **WPF**.

I'm trying to get it to work in **Silverlight**.

But it gives me these **errors**:

```
TextBlock does not contain a definition for ToolTip.
Cursors does not contain a definition for Help.
ToolTipService does not contain a definition for SetInitialShowDelay.
```

**How can I get this to work in Silverlight?**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace TestHover29282
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AddCustomer("Jim Smith");
            AddCustomer("Joe Jones");
            AddCustomer("Angie Jones");
            AddCustomer("Josh Smith");
        }

        void AddCustomer(string name)
        {
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = name;
            ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
            tt.Content = "This is some info on " + name + ".";
            tb.ToolTip = tt;
            tt.Cursor = Cursors.Help;
            ToolTipService.SetInitialShowDelay(tb, 0);

            MainStackPanel.Children.Add(tb);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tooltips are added to Silverlight controls using an attached property provided by the ToolTipService.  There is no `SetInitialShowDelay` in Silverlight's version nor is there a `Help` cursor on the `Cursors` type.

```
    void AddCustomer(string name)
    {
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Text = name;
        ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
        tt.Content = "This is some info on " + name + ".";
        ToolTipService.SetToolTip(tb, tt);

        MainStackPanel.Children.Add(tb);
    }
```