# add tooltip to check box Or radiobutton in runtime silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I am building a control where i put control like checkbox or radiobuttons, i would like know if is possible add a tooltip fore each built control.
Thank you.

Comment: fixed using link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469339/how-to-convert-this-code-based-wpf-tooltip-to-silverlight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this post](http://eightyeightpercentnerd.blogspot.com/2008/06/c-using-tooltipservice.html). The code is copied from there.

```
ToolTip nameTip = new ToolTip();
nameTip.Content = "Testing ToolTipService";
ToolTipService.SetToolTip(myCanvas, nameTip);
```